# PHP: cannot declare class because the name is already in use

Tags: php, oop

I have 5 scripts:

1. `database.php`
2. `parent.php`
3. `child1.php`
4. `child2.php`
5. `somescript.php`

`parent.php` class looks like this:

```
include 'database.php';

class Parent {
    public $db;
    function __construct() {
        $this->db = new Database();
    }
}
```

The `child1.php` and `child2.php` classes looks like this:

```
include 'parent.php';

class Child1 extends Parent {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function useDb() {
        $this->db->some_db_operation();
    }
}
```

**The problem**

When I try to include both child1 and child2 in somescript.php, it returns the following error:

> cannot declare class Database because the name is already in use in
>   database.php on line 4 *(this is the line which contains words 'class Database')*

But if I include only a single file (child1 or child2), it works great.

How do I correct that?

Answer (score 68):

You want to use [include_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) or [require_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php). The other option would be to create an additional file with all your class includes in the correct order so they don't need to call includes themselves:

"classes.php"

```
include 'database.php';
include 'parent.php';
include 'child1.php';
include 'child2.php';
```

Then you just need:

```
require_once('classes.php');
```

Comment: I've used include_once everywhere in my project and this still happens. It used to work before

Comment: @Dan, you still need to make sure the order of your includes is correct so that when a class is defined the parent class(es) have already been included.

Comment: This answer should be accepted. Solves the issue, goes to the point and provides examples.

Comment: Same this resolved the issue so it should be accepted

Answer (score 13):

try to use use `include_once`or `require_once` instead of `include` or `require`

Answer (score 5):

Another option to include_once or require_once is to use class autoloading. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 5):

You should use require_once and include_once. Inside parent.php use

```
include_once 'database.php';
```

And inside child1.php and child2.php use

```
include_once 'parent.php';
```

Answer (score 2):

Class Parent cannot be declared because it is PHP reserved keyword so in effect it's already in use

Comment: I've changed the name of my ErrorController Class from _'Error.php'_ to 'ErrorHandler.php' and fixed it. Since PHP 7 the Error Class is reserved keyword and therefore already in use [https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.error.php]

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before and to fix this,
Just make sure :

1. You did not create an instance of this class before
2. If you call this from a class method, make sure the __destruct is set on the class you called from.

My problem (before) :
I had class : Core, Router, Permissions and Render
Core include's the Router class, Router then calls Permissions class, then Router __destruct calls the Render class and the error "Cannot declare class because the name is already in use" appeared.

Solution :
I added __destruct on Permission class and the __destruct was empty and it's fixed...