# Using extends in more than one file and generating an error

Tags: php

I'm using extends in php, I have a class named person and a category and both extends model

**Category.php**

```
include ("./model/Model.php");
class Category extends Model  {

}
```

**Person.php**

```
include ("./model/Model.php");
class Person extends Model  {

}
```

**Model.php**

```
class Model{ // this is line 3
}
```

but when I try to use one of the classes the error appears

> Fatal error: Cannot declare class Model, because the name is already
>   in use in C:\wamp64\www\api\model\Model.php on line 3

Comment: You could also use an autoload function to include classes only when they are used. http://php.net/autoload

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: cannot declare class because the name is already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42682501/php-cannot-declare-class-because-the-name-is-already-in-use)

Comment: Toss my vote in as well for `spl_autoload_register`. Forgo all the `include` and `require` mash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
include ("./model/Model.php");
```

with

```
include_once ("./model/Model.php");
```

From the docs:

> This is a behavior similar to the include statement, with the only difference being that if the code from a file has already been included, it will not be included again, and include_once returns TRUE

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

Comment: I have other include in my project I better swap for include_once?

Comment: Probably, if it's the same case.