# PHP reports "Cannot redeclare class" in PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer in a script like this:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
```

This is working, but I have another script that also needs to use it. When I attempt to redeclare it I get the following error because that file is already included...

```
Cannot declare class PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception
```

I want to make sure it has been declared and if not load it on this new page. I have tried this but with no luck...

```
if (!class_exists("PHPMailer\\PHPMailer\\Exception")) {

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
    require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

}
```

Comment: You should use either require or "use" why are you using both? Try to remove the require of PHPMailer.

Comment: @Eduardo They’re not mutually exclusive, you do need both.

Comment: What’s the complete error message, where does it point to the class having been previously declared?

Comment: I never had the use case of using both. :( at least using Laravel.

Comment: I don't need to use both, but in the second script I wanted to check it had already been initialized and then if not run the use and require

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: cannot declare class because the name is already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42682501/php-cannot-declare-class-because-the-name-is-already-in-use)

Comment: So remove the require of the exception and tell us if worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708140/php-fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-class)

Comment: For `class_exists("PHPMailer\\PHPMailer\\Exception")` set the second argument to false - `class_exists ( string $class_name [, bool $autoload = TRUE ] )`  And I would use `PHPMailer::class` instead of typing it out.  OR you can just use `requre_once`

Comment: @Eduardo Cause Laravel uses an auto loader by default. If you don’t have that, you still need to `require` the file. Just `use` doesn’t do that, it merely aliases namespaces.

Comment: @deceze But these 'use' statement  on the example code doesn't mean that the namespace is " loaded " and he is able to use the 'use' statement. And than there is no need to use the require?

Comment: @Eduardo No. `use` literally just makes namespaced names shorter; it establishes an alias within the current file. Nothing more, nothing less. Note that you can omit `use` statements entirely and write `$pm = new \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;` directly for exactly the same result.

Comment: I think i understand what you are saying, but if he had removed the require of phpmailer. Wouldnt it still work? Or the "use" is using a namespace imported through that require ?

Comment: @Eduardo We don't know whether it would still work if OP removed the `require`. *If* OP has an autoloader configured which would load the class, then it might still work. Otherwise it won't. Regardless of the use of `use`.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the conversation. Made me thing about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) is for.

> The require_once statement is identical to require except PHP will
>   check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include
>   (require) it again.